# CodeIgniter Hooks for Active Record library

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I need some help to understand CodeIgniter's hook logic to adapt the code to my needs.

The page : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

In fact, I had to modify the database driver for MySQL from this :

```
function _from_tables($tables)
{
    if ( ! is_array($tables))
    {
        $tables = array($tables);
    }
return '('.implode(', ', $tables).')';
}
```

to this :

```
function _from_tables($tables)
{
    if ( ! is_array($tables))
    {
        $tables = array($tables);
    }
return implode(', ', $tables);
}
```

I made this mod to use UNION queries using Active Record library.

Can someone help me to make a hook in order to prevent my modification from being overwritten when I update the core system ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you're looking for customized libraries, not hooks.  See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html -> replacing libraries with your own versions.  You can extend the DB driver and replace a method or two with your own custom version.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the instructions for extending the db drivers on the [CodeIgniter Wiki - Extending Database Drivers](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers)

> **The solution comes in 3 simple steps:**
>
> 1) Extend your loader class by creating the file MY_Loader.php. Put it
>   into your libraries directory in the application path (or if you are
>   using CI 2.x.x then put it into application\core\ path):
>
> 2) Add the following function to your MY_Loader class:
>
> 3) Create your Database driver extension class, that you name
>   MY_DB_mysql_driver.php (or substitute the mysql part for whatever
>   driver you use - do that also for the classnames in the code below!).
>   Put this file also in your applications libraries directory:

Your custom DB driver will look like this

```
class MY_DB_mysql_driver extends CI_DB_mysql_driver {

  function __construct($params){
    parent::__construct($params);
    log_message('debug', 'Extended DB driver class instantiated!');
  }

  function _from_tables($tables)
  {
      if ( ! is_array($tables))
      {
          $tables = array($tables);
      }
      return implode(', ', $tables);
  }

}
```

Comment: I didn't know I could modify CI functions with helpers ! I did for a few functions I needed, but not for core :) Thanks !

Comment: I get the following errors when using your method :


    A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: 8192
    Message: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated
    Filename: core/MY_Loader.php
    Line Number: 32

What can I do ?

Comment: remove the `&` in `$db =& new $my_driver(get_object_vars($db));`

Comment: I now get Fatal error: Call to undefined method MY_DB_mysql_driver::where() in \system\libraries\Session.php on line 201

I put my file MY_DB_mysql_driver.php in applciation/libraries, and MY_Loader.php in applciation/core/, am I right ?

Comment: You should probably ask another question about that.  There won't be enough space in the comment area to debug the issue