# CodeIgniter modifications extending database drivers for using them with UNION queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, frameworks

My goal is to use UNION queries in CodeIgniter Active Record.

Some people suggested to me to use the method $this->db->last_query(); to get the queries I want, then combining it with UNION.

Problem is that $this->db->from(); method used in the MySQL driver in Active Record uses parenthesis around the from clause (ex: SELECT * FROM ('table') ) and prevents me to use UNION.

So I checked again and found I could modify the _from_tables function defined in the

```
system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php
```

I changed the code :

```
function _from_tables($tables)
{
    if ( ! is_array($tables))
    {
        $tables = array($tables);
    }
return '('.implode(', ', $tables).')';
}
```

to this :

```
function _from_tables($tables)
{
    if ( ! is_array($tables))
    {
        $tables = array($tables);
    }
return implode(', ', $tables);
}
```

But if I 
I asked a question here on how to extend CI mysql driver (in fact, I only want to replace the from method with a custom one) :
[CodeIgniter Hooks for Active Record library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061724/codeigniter-hooks-for-active-record-library) and I was proposed to ask a new question.

So one user proposed to add two files, which I did, in my folders:

```
application/libraries/MY_DB_mysql_driver.php
application/core/MY_Loader.php
```

I get these errors while using this method :

```
 A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 8192 Message: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated Filename: core/MY_Loader.php Line Number: 32
```

So I modified the script he gave me (you can see it at https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers) by deleting the & in :

```
$db =& new $my_driver(get_object_vars($db));
```

I now get the following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MY_DB_mysql_driver::where() in \system\libraries\Session.php
```

If someone has done it without tweaking system folder, please help :(

Comment: are we supposed to guess what errors you are getting? (Also all core extensions go into the core directory, and not into libraries anymore)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Hooks for Active Record library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061724/codeigniter-hooks-for-active-record-library)

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat Actually I'm not sure that this is duplicate, the problem has not been solved by the given answer.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat Actually, the user who helped me asked me if I could make a new question, which I did (this is my post you are referring to)

For the errors I am getting, they are documented in my other question.

Comment: So then this is really weird. Please pack everything we need to know into one question and make everything clear. I think it's not very polite to make the people you want to help you search for your problem by themselves.

Comment: I updated and packed all the information you might need to help me